# Performance Issue i Arango query while returning the whole Object

Tags: performance, spring-boot, query-optimization, arangodb

I am new to ArangoDB . Needed some help in improving performance of a query .

> Tech specs: ArangoDb(3.6.2) , Java 8 Springboot application(2.xx) .

I am trying to run a query where it returns an object after merging data from couple of Graphs . 
The query runs infinitely when i directly return the object , where it runs faster(like 75 secs) when i just return an element of the object .

```
for d in data
        return d
```

Output:

```
[{
accntDtl:{ //account detials here
         },
accntPrfl:{//accnt profile here
            },
//few other parameters
}]
```

`return d`  - runs infinitely .

whereas, `return d.accnt[0].accntDtl[0].accntId` - executes in 75 secs..

What can be a possible solution to increase its performance ?

**Note:** This query returns around 2 million record .

For confidentiality purpose , i am unable to post the whole query here .

Thanks in advance .

Updates: Included AqlQueryOptions for streaming .

```
aqlQueryOptions.stream(true),aqlQueryOptions.batchSize(10000)
```

Consuming the same :

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
  result = cursor.next();
  //deserilize result as doc
  resultList.add(doc)
  ..... processing the data
}
```

But this iteration is happening 1 by 1 and not in a batch of 10,000 as specified in the batchSize param .
I am pretty sure, the way am consuming the cursor is not advisable . Kindly suggest the best way to consume this data in a batch of 10,000 at each iteration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such query would be beneficial using a streaming cursor, setting `stream` to `true` on AQL cursor creation.

Here is the reference documentation:

- for Spring Data ArangoDB (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/integrations/spring-data-arangodb/reference-version-4/repositories/queries/#aql-query-options)
- ArangoDB Java Driver (https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/7.1.0/com/arangodb/model/AqlQueryOptions.html#stream(java.lang.Boolean))

Comment: Thanks @rashtao , I have updated the streaming logic in the code above, but am still not able to consume the cursor data in a batch of 10,000 as specified in the queryOptions param . Kindly help me with the proper approach to consume this , and any example would be really helpful to this Novice ArangoDB developer .

Comment: The Java driver does not allow you to consume the data in batches, but just requesting it in batches! It means that the Java `ArangoCursor` imeplements `Iterator` and this offers you the API to consume results one by one, calling `cursor.next()` as you are doing.
Under the hood, the driver requests data in batches (of 10,000 in your case), fetching it as you entirely consumed the previous batch. So it will generate a request as you create the cursor, then when you consume the 10.001st element , then on the 20.001st and so on.